# How to restore a model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

First I trained a  model using tf.contrib.gan as bellow, and I was able to train the model.

```
tf.contrib.gan.gan_train(
        train_ops,
        hooks=(
                [tf.train.StopAtStepHook(num_steps=FLAGS.max_number_of_steps),
                 tf.train.LoggingTensorHook([status_message], every_n_iter=10)] +
                sync_hooks),
        logdir=FLAGS.train_log_dir,
        master=FLAGS.master,
        is_chief=FLAGS.task == 0,
        config=conf
    )
```

Then I want to evaluate the model. When trying to restore the checkpoints in the following way,

```
with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
  real_images, one_hot_labels, _, num_classes = data_provider.provide_data(
    FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.dataset_dir)
  logits, end_points_des, feature, net = dcgan.discriminator(real_images)

  variables_to_restore = slim.get_model_variables()
  restorer = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
          ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
          restorer.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

I am getting this exception:

```
      2018-04-11 20:05:03.304089: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key Discriminator/fully_connected_layer2/weights not found in checkpoint
      2018-04-11 20:05:03.304280: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key Discriminator/conv0/BatchNorm/Discriminator/conv0/BatchNorm/moving_mean/local_step not found in checkpoint
      2018-04-11 20:05:03.304484: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key Discriminator/conv0/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
      2018-04-11 20:05:03.305197: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key Discriminator/fully_connected_layer2/biases not found in checkpoint
```

I am using TF 1.7rc1

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there was a problem in the generated graph.  These are steps I did in order to solve this problem.

Step 1: 
 print all the variable in the checkpoit file using the following code

```
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name, '')
```

Step2: Then I noticed  each key consists a duplication of the first scope ('Discriminator') which was set, but when I try to load model, it does not consist of that part. Thus I had to remove that additional part in the following way,

```
  def name_in_checkpoint(var):
      if "Discriminator/" in var.op.name:
         return var.op.name.replace("Discriminator/", "Discriminator/Discriminator/")

  logits, end_points_des, feature, net = dcgan.discriminator(real_images) 
  variables_to_restore = slim.get_model_variables()
  variables_to_restore = {name_in_checkpoint(var): var for var in variables_to_restore}
  restorer = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
```

Step 3: Then I was able to load the model successfully as bellow.

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
restorer.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

Hope this will help somebody who may be encountered the same problem.